# Django migrate app using south - duplicate initial

Tags: django, django-south

I'm trying to migrate django apps, and i have problem with one. When i run

```
python manage.py migrate --list |grep -v "*"
```

i get output

```
dbtemplates
  ( ) 0001_initial
  ( ) 0002_auto__del_unique_template_name
  ( ) 0003_initial
```

I jut downloaded dbtemplates package, and in downloaded folder migrations are 3 files:

```
__init__.py
0001_initial.py
0002_auto__del_unique_template_name.py
```

So in my django project `0003` shouldn't be here i think. Should i remove `0003`, mark as fake? If i need to remove `0003` migration, where can i find this package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
python manage.py shell
[1]: import dbtemplates
[2]: dbtemplates
```

This show the path package

Comment: Do I need to remove 0003 file?

Comment: I think so. And is possible (if you executed migrate command) that you have to delete a row of the south_migrationhistory table.